Want to redirect to react component based on metamask address
I'm building an Identification management dApp, in which I have to redirect to a different component based on selected MetaMask account address.
For example, if I'm an applicant then I will be redirected to ./applicant  when I connect to my particular MetaMask account.
This is my app.jsx :
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link,
  Navigate,

} from "react-router-dom";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import abi from "./contractJson/chai.json";
import PInfo from "./components/frontend/PInfo";
import GInfo from "./components/backend/GInfo";
import Edit from "./components/frontend/requEdit";
import Ap from "./components/Appli";
import NI from "./components/frontend/NIDsta";
import LOG from "./components/LocalGov";
import NID from "./components/frontend/getNID";
import GEDIT from "./components/backend/getEdit"
import WEL from "./components/welcome"
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    provider: null,
    signer: null,
    contract: null,
  });

  const [account, setAccount] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = async () => {
      const contractAddress = "0xdaAE5bF9F3f8146584876ad0608E52Dd50bB82CB";
      const contractABI = abi.abi;

      try {
        if (!window.ethereum) {
          alert("Please install MetaMask!");
        }
        const { ethereum } = window;
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });

        window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        setAccount(accounts[0]);

        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();

        const contract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddress,
          contractABI,
          signer
        );
    
        // console.log(contract);
        setState({ provider, signer, contract });
          
 

      
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message || "Error occurred while initializing.");
      }
    };
    initialize();

    const redirectBasedOnAccount = (account) => {

      if (account === "0x1613d968665C978C3a5b7A08653185377DFbEDb8") {
        console.log("In redirection")
        return <Navigate to="/applicant" replace />;
      } else if (account === "0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65") {
        return <Navigate to="/LocalGov" replace />;
      }
      // Handle other accounts or default route if not matched
     
    };

    redirectBasedOnAccount(account)
  }, [account]);

   
 
  

  return (
    <>
        
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<WEL></WEL>}></Route>
        <Route path="/applicant" element={<Ap></Ap>}></Route>
        <Route path="/LocalGov" element={<LOG></LOG>}></Route>


        <Route path="/apply" element={<PInfo state={state} />}></Route>

        <Route path="/admin" element={<GInfo state={state} />}></Route>
        <Route path="/RequestEdit" element={<Edit></Edit>}></Route>
        <Route path="/Status" element={<NI></NI>}></Route>
        <Route path="/getnid" element={<NID></NID>}></Route>
        <Route path="/getEditInfo" element={<GEDIT></GEDIT>}></Route>
      </Routes>

   
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I have tried this function:
const redirectBasedOnAccount = (account) => {

      if (account === "0x1613d968665C978C3a5b7A08653185377DFbEDb8") {
        console.log("In redirection")
        return <Navigate to="/applicant" replace />;
      } else if (account === "0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65") {
        return <Navigate to="/LocalGov" replace />;
      }
      // Handle other accounts or default route if not matched
     
    };

 import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link,
  Navigate,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

const Appli = ({ state, account }) => {

  const [navigateTo, setNavigateTo] = useState(null);
    


  if (account === "0x1613d968665C978C3a5b7A08653185377DFbEDb8") {
    return (
      <>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
            <Link >Apply Now</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/RequestEdit">Reuest For Edit </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/Status"> Check Status</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/getnid"> Get NID</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </>
    );
  }
  
};

export default Appli;

this is my appli.jsx file
But, it's still not working.
Here's my GitHub repo containing the full project.

Kindly please accept the previous answer as well as this answer, if they helped you out, so that they can be helpful for others facing the similar problem as well.

Hi , did already, I was struglling , they seems to have issue for me to accept answer with low repuataions

Okay. No worries. Thanks.

Instead of defining and calling your redirectBasedOnAccount function inside useEffect. You need to define it outside its scope, and call the same inside the return of your App.jsx.
Also, you need to convert the addresses to lowercase while comparing, because the eth_requestAccounts returns the account addresses in lowercase.
Here's the revised code for App.jsx:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link,
  Navigate,

} from "react-router-dom";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import abi from "./contractJson/chai.json";
import PInfo from "./components/frontend/PInfo";
import GInfo from "./components/backend/GInfo";
import Edit from "./components/frontend/requEdit";
import Ap from "./components/Appli";
import NI from "./components/frontend/NIDsta";
import LOG from "./components/LocalGov";
import NID from "./components/frontend/getNID";
import GEDIT from "./components/backend/getEdit"
import WEL from "./components/welcome"
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    provider: null,
    signer: null,
    contract: null,
  });

  const [account, setAccount] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = async () => {
      const contractAddress = "0xdaAE5bF9F3f8146584876ad0608E52Dd50bB82CB";
      const contractABI = abi.abi;

      try {
        if (!window.ethereum) {
          alert("Please install MetaMask!");
        }
        const { ethereum } = window;
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });

        window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        setAccount(accounts[0]);

        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();

        const contract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddress,
          contractABI,
          signer
        );

        // console.log(contract);
        setState({ provider, signer, contract });




      } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message || "Error occurred while initializing.");
      }
    };
    initialize();
  }, [account]);


  const redirectBasedOnAccount = (account) => {

    if (account === "0x1613d968665C978C3a5b7A08653185377DFbEDb8".toLowerCase()) {
      console.log("In redirection")
      return <Navigate to="/applicant" replace />;
    } else if (account === "0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65".toLowerCase()) {
      return <Navigate to="/LocalGov" replace />;
    }
    // Handle other accounts or default route if not matched

  };


  return (
    <>

      {redirectBasedOnAccount(account)}

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<WEL></WEL>}></Route>
        <Route path="/applicant" element={<Ap></Ap>}></Route>
        <Route path="/LocalGov" element={<LOG></LOG>}></Route>


        <Route path="/apply" element={<PInfo state={state} />}></Route>

        <Route path="/admin" element={<GInfo state={state} />}></Route>
        <Route path="/RequestEdit" element={<Edit></Edit>}></Route>
        <Route path="/Status" element={<NI></NI>}></Route>
        <Route path="/getnid" element={<NID></NID>}></Route>
        <Route path="/getEditInfo" element={<GEDIT></GEDIT>}></Route>
      </Routes>


    </>
  );
}

export default App;


It works , thanks a lot

You're welcome. Happy coding!

I hope this will find you
I am not a react expert trying to improve
can you see this one


     return <Navigate to="/applicant" replace />;
when I am navigating to /applicant 

the applicant component has 4 links /apply ,/editreauest like this 

when I click on apply now it wont let me to redirectted to /apply as I am navigateed to /applicant connecting to a account 

How can I fix this , I used several approach not working like useNavigate

I have added my appli.jsx file in the question

@Shorna, I've answered. Please check.
